Diagnostic details: - The last unmovable file appears to be: \$Mft::$DATA
I tried to shrink my c drive but i noticed that there's a point i tried to fix it but during the shrink phase i got this defrag Diagnostic details:

The last unmovable file appears to be: $Mft::$DATA
The last cluster of the file is: 0x525a8db
Shrink potential target (LCN address): 0xb8f12c
The NTFS file flags are: -S--D
Shrink phase: 
any solutions for this?
thanks in advance,


A possible solution: copy all the files and folder to another drive (or partition), reformat the drive and move the files back to the original drive.

i only have the c drive i never had this problem before until now after i did reformat my to factory rest and updated to windows 11 so technically my c drive contains the OS
